# Display 90% of the image height using CSS?

Tags: css

I want to hide the bottom part of the image and only display the top 90% of the image,

I've tried to use

```
transform: translateY(10%);
```

and adding to the parent div the following property:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

but this makes an empty 10% on top of the image, I do not want empty space on top of the image how can I achieve that?

Comment: maybe using clip-path: inset(10% 0 0 0) [or inset(0 0 10% 0) ]

Answer (score 1):

You could absolute position the image in a relative container with `overflow: hidden`. Just make sure the parent div is actually 90% of the height and the image is positioned `top: 0%`.

Comment: Can I make sure that the parent div is 90% of the image without js?

Comment: Depends. If your image has a fixed (and known) size, you could give that to your container (and scale the img to fill it up). On the other hand you could scale the image inside the container to 110%.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it this way, I would suggest that you set the height of the image to 110% instead of 90%:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-container {
    background-color: steelblue;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
    height: 110%;
}
```

---

or if you know the size of the image, you can use object-fit and object-position. Let's say that the height of the image is 500px, then 90% of it would be 450px, then your css would be:

```
.image-container img {
    height: 450px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top;
}
```

Comment: this is a big brain move right here